# Split class with many methods

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class called Operand with lots of private methods:

```
class Operand : public OperandBase
{
    //Lots of private methods here
};
```

And i am not violating the single responsability principle, its just that my Operand class really needs lots of methods (or at least lots from my point of view), but i do know it looks ugly and its difficult keep working on this class, so i created an ExOperand class where i manage all the public interface to the client (just for the sake of splitting):

```
class ExOperand : public Operand
{
    //Implement public interface
};
```

This is looks like a lame solution that i dont want to use. Is there any standard way to split class file into multiple definitions or some guide line when this happens? The number of methods i have in the Operand class are 16 and i think its a little too much for my own standard (i usually make classes with 5-10 methods tops). Thanks

Comment: You have to declare the interface (the actual `class` declaration) in one spot (assuming you don't (ab)use inheritance like this), but if you want you can split the implementation across as many files as you would like.

Comment: Can i split the declaration (.h file) of class between multiple headers files?

Comment: Not without using inheritance, as you show here.

Comment: Sometimes you can pretend and use **namespaces** as class with lots of functions defined in many different files.